# Base change of topogical spaces VS Base change of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

In algebraic geometry, we have the following famous base change theorem [Hartshorne III Theorem 12.11]:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a projective morphism of noetherian schemes, and let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$, flat over $X$. Let $y$ be a point of $Y$. Then if the natural map 
>   $$\varphi^i(y): R^i f_*(\mathcal F)\otimes k(y)\to H^i(X_y,\mathcal F_y)$$
>   is surjecitve, then it is an isomorphism.

On the other hand, in the category of topogical spaces, we also have a base change theorem as above [*Cohomology of sheaves* lversen, Birger Theorem 1.4 P315 ]

> Let $f:X\to Y$ denote a continuous proper map between compact spaces. For $y\in Y$ we have a natural isomorphism
>   $$(R^i f_*\mathcal F)_y\cong H^i(f^{-1}(y),\mathcal F);  i\in\mathbb Z$$ 
>   as $\mathcal F$ varies through the category of sheaves on $X$.

In the theorem of base change of topological spaces, we have a very general result: we do not ask for any conditions for the sheaf $\mathcal F$, but we can always get an isomorphism. However, in the theorem of base change of schemes, even we suppose that the sheaf $\mathcal F$ is flat, we do not have an isomorphism in the general cases. So I am a litte confused. I think that the second theorem is more general, and the first theorem is just a special case of the second one. Why do we just get a weaker result?

PS. In the book of lversen, he suppose that the topological spaces are Hausdorff. But we can consider the category of complex analytic spaces in which we also have a similar theorem as the first one.

Comment: No the first one is not a special case of the second. The difference lies between the pullback functors. In the second case, it is just the pullback of sheaves $i^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ which is exact, in the second this is the pullback of quasi-coherent modules $i^*\mathcal{F}=i^{-1}\mathcal{F}\otimes_{i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y} k(y)$. The second one is not exact. That is why the flatness condition appears. But we also need conditions to ensure that $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ is also flat or that certain a certain exact sequence remains exact after pulling back.

Comment: @Roland Your explication is very clear. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Roland Sorry. I understand your last comment and the difference between those two definitions for pullback functors, but in the statement of  the theorems, we do not use pullback functor. So how does this cause the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you do. In the first theorem, $R^if_*\mathcal{F}\otimes k(y)$ is in fact, $i^*R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ where $i:y\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion. And $H^i(X_y,\mathcal{F}_y)=H^i(X_y,i^*\mathcal{F})$. In the second theorem, the equality is in fact $i^{-1}R^if_*\mathcal{F}=H^i(f^{-1}(y),i^{-1}\mathcal{F})$.

Comment: @Roland So, if we let $i: y\to Y$ and let $j: X_y\to X$, the first statement is exactement as: $i^*R^i f_*(\mathcal F)\to H^i(X_y,j^*\mathcal F)$, and the map is induced by a natural way of base change. Right?

Comment: Yes that is it.